# Multiple prism modules with same view name

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

How can I handle multiple modules that use the same view name?

For reference, I'm using `Ninject`, but this should be the same with `Unity`

If I have 2 modules, `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`, and both modules have a view called `ViewX`, how would this work? I thought the point of navigating with modules is that I could do `RegionManager.RequestNavigation("MainRegion", "ViewX")` and prism would navigate to whichever module contained that view. Since there are 2, it'll grab the first one, but the IoC container will blow up because there are 2 registrations for `object` that are named `ViewX`.

I could easily make the registration like `ModuleA,ViewX`, `ModuleB,ViewX`, but doesn't that completely defeat the purpose?

What is a good way to handle this?

Comment: Wow, 2 down votes in a couple minutes. If you would explain why, maybe I could just delete this question.

Comment: I don't know where the downvotes come from; for me, this is a good question.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but you might be getting downvotes because *what is a good way to handle this* is subjective.

Comment: Well, if it's subjective, then someone could have said so, and given the most common 3 ways of doing it or something. Thanks to @dymanoid for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve your issue.

The first one you have already described in your question: just register your view objects with "full qualified" keys containing your module names. Note that the extension method  `RequestNavigate(this IRegionManager regionManager, string regionName, string source)` accepts an `URI` string as the `source` argument, so that wouldn't break the paradigm: you provide a full URI of your view.

Another possibility is to provide a custom implementation of the `IServiceLocator` interface. You can register it in your IoC container in your bootstrapper. Prism instantiates a new view requesting an instance from current `IServiceLocator`: `newRegionItem = this.serviceLocator.GetInstance<object>(candidateTargetContract)`. For example, the `IServiceLocator` implementation for MEF throws an exception if multiple exports match the requested contract:

```
IEnumerable<Lazy<object, object>> exports = this.compositionContainer.GetExports(serviceType, null, key);
if ((exports != null) && (exports.Count() > 0))
{
    // If there is more than one value, this will throw an InvalidOperationException, 
    // which will be wrapped by the base class as an ActivationException.
    return exports.Single().Value;
}
```

You can change this behavior to whatever you like, e.g. `return exports.First().Value`.